# Get selected record from datagrid wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, indexing

I've got the table in picture. According to post field checkbox , if its checked I write into a file and delete those records from my database. if its not checked records will remain in my database.Problem is when I then try to access to those records I get an exception(cant find that onject) because I am trying to access with datagrid.SelectedIndex  its giving me datagrid index and not record index. Is there any way of getting record index? I ve got automatic index as incremented by 1 as unique Id for each record.

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I found the answer , `System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid dataGrid = sender as System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid;
            DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(e.Row.Item);
            BridgeDesktopApp.SalesOrder nn = (SalesOrder) row.Item;
            int xcxc = nn.orderId;`

Answer (score 0):

if you use a viewmodel or something you can simply use a command and the selected datagridrow as commandparameter. in your command you can easily access your underlining data and check your "Post" property and the wirte your file and delete the row from your collection.

```
<Buttons Command="{Binding WriteCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyDataGridCtrl, Path=SelectedItem}" />
```

if you have a DataTable as Datasource your Command could look like the following

```
 private DelegateCommand<DataRowView> _writeCommand ;
 public ICommand WriteCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return this._writeCommand ??
                   (this._writeCommand = new DelegateCommand<DataRowView>(this.WriteCommandExecute, this.CanWriteCommandExecute));
        }
    }

 private bool CanEditDataCommandExecute(DataRowView rowToWrite)
    {
        return rowToWrite!= null && (bool)rowToWrite["Post"];//if post is a bool
    }

  private void EditDataCommandExecute(DataRowView rowToWrite)
    {
        if (!this.CanEditDataCommandExecute(rowToWrite))
            return;

        //do your stuff here
    }
```